# Can I use lower on a nested query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery

It's been a while since I used SQL but getting my hands dirty again. I'm getting a error while trying to lowercase a list of strings.

I have two queries that I want to turn into one, and each works on their own:

```
    select ticker from "General" g4 where industry = (select industry from "General" g3 where g3.ticker = 'IBM.US');
ticker
NSIT.US
SNX.US
NRILY.US
WIT.US
```

This returns a list of tickers based on the industry of the ticker variable(in this case all companies in the same industry as IBM)

then I want to get the average revenue for each company in that year:

```
select year, AVG(revenue) AS AVGrevenue  from revenue r where lower(ticker) = lower('ibm.us') GROUP BY c.year;
works awesome:

2013    2750040.000000000000
2014    3675122.000000000000
2015    3455017.000000000000
2016    2140280.000000000000
2017    3401381.000000000000
```

but when I combine it, it does not work:

Error occurred during SQL query execution

```
select year, AVG(revenue) AS AVGrevenue  
from revenue r 
where lower(ticker) = lower(

select ticker from "General" g4 where industry = (select industry from "General" g3 where g3.ticker = 'IBM.US')

) 
GROUP BY r.year;
```

I get this error:

```
Reason:
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
  Position: 635
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could*, but I would suggest moving the `lower()` *into* the query:

```
where lower(ticker) = (select lower(g4.ticker)
                       from "General" g4
                       where industry = (select industry from "General" g3 where g3.ticker = 'IBM.US')

                       )
```

If you wanted the subquery to be an argument to `lower()`, that is also allowed by you need an extra level of parentheses:

```
where lower(ticker) = lower( (select g4.ticker
                              from "General" g4
                              where industry = (select industry from "General" g3 where g3.ticker = 'IBM.US')

                             ) 
                           )
```

One set of parentheses is for the function call.  The second is for the correlated subquery.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I just tried that and got this error - SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Where is it coming from? I'm not sure

Comment: I think I fixed it, I changed = to "in"

Comment: @Lostsoul . . . `in` would be how you would solve.  However, if you are expecting at most one row and `=` fails, then something might be wrong with the query logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You  should put lower() inside the select.

```
select year, AVG(revenue) AS AVGrevenue  
from revenue r 
where lower(ticker) = 
(
select lower(ticker) from "General" g4 where industry = (select industry from "General" g3 where g3.ticker = 'IBM.US')
)
GROUP BY r.year;
```